# Installed PyCharm successfully on Debian, but cannot run it

Tags: debian, python

I installed PyCharm successfully.

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

But I cannot find it on the applications menu, nor run it form the terminal `pycharm-community`.

```
Setting up snapd (2.49-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.recovery-chooser-trigger.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.recovery-chooser-trigger.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.seeded.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/cloud-final.service.wants/snapd.seeded.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.seeded.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.service → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket → /lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket.
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
2021-08-29T16:33:54+03:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...
core 16-2.51.4 from Canonical✓ installed
$ sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
pycharm-community 2021.2.1 from jetbrains✓ installed
```

Comment: What release of Debian are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in Debian Bullseye, `Pycharm` doesn't show up in the applications menu.

The binary is located at `/snap/bin/pycharm-community`.

You either need to add `/snap/bin` to your environment:

```
echo PATH=/snap/bin/:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

And then:

```
pycharm-community
```

Or use the full path to the binary:

```
/snap/bin/pycharm-community
```

If you haven't already, you also need to install the following packages:

```
libxtst-dev 
libxtst6
libxrender-dev
libxrender1
```

After that, it will launch.

Comment: what cmd to install these? what do they do?

Comment: `$ sudo /snap/bin/pycharm-community
[sudo] password: 
/var not root-owned 0:1000
`

Comment: @Elad don’t use `sudo`.

Comment: @Elad Benda Install the packages with `apt` as sudo. Launch the binary as your regular account without sudo.